# Have large human bones been used as measuring instruments?

Tags: ancient-history, prehistory

> Have any of the six types of large bones from the arms<sup>**1**</sup> or legs<sup>**2**</sup> of human beings ever been used (to a significant or considerable extent), in ancient or prehistoric times, as measuring instruments for estimating lengths or distances ?

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>The [humerus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humerus) (upper arm), the [ulna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulna) and the [radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_(bone)) (forearm).</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup> <sub>The [femur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femur) (upper leg), the [tibia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibia) and the [fibula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibula) (lower leg).</sub>

Comment: Grab a rope with right hand, supporting it with the left, and extend arms. One fathom. With right hand drop rope; grab rope out of left hand; and extend arms again. Two fathoms. Repeat until desired length of rope has been measured. What's so "*impractical*" about that - it seems imminently practical to me. Note that *fathoms* are traditional units for measuring both *ropes* and such things as *soundings* that are in turn **measured by ropes**.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I am talking about feet, not fathoms. It is far easier or more comfortable to extend the palm than to bend it, when measuring with the forearm.

Comment: SO: What is your question? this is a W&A site, NOT a forum. [FAQ on How to ask a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: The actual question is the title and first paragraph. What follows below the horizontal line is what prompted me to ask the question in the first place (so that no-one may accuse me of asking weird questions for no reason).

Comment: A ["*noun phrase*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) is not a question. A ["*question*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) is a complete interrogative sentence ended with a question mark ("?").

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: And the first paragraph is what, exactly ? The noun phrase is the question's title.

Comment: @Lucian I think the premise is flawed: "The “foot” defined as the sixth part of a fathom" - AFAIK, historically foot was defined as the length of a, well, human foot (probably in some kind of footwear, since the measurement unit tends to be slightly bigger than the average foot of a human in time and locale that unit was used in). Also, pre-XIX century fathom varied from 5 to 7 feet AND, when it was standartized, it was as 1/1000th of a nautical mile (6.08ft); the 6ft fathom was only used because it was simpler to measure.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov: (1). Footwear has nothing to do with it. The length of the sole of the foot is the same as the [span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_(unit)). All units are multiples of the span (two to a cubit, three to an arm, four to a yard, five to an ell, eight to a fathom). Since the span subdivides nicely into three palms, we have 24 palms to a fathom. But 12 and 24 divide not just by threes, but also by fours. Hence, four palms to the *foot*. (2). Regardless of whether my intuition is right or wrong, I am still very curious about finding an answer to the main question.

Comment: The notion of *internationally standardized units* is new since the French Revolution's introduction of the metric System, and its subsequent export to the rest of Western Europe by Napoleon Bonaparte. Just [in Germany alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolete_German_units_of_measurement#Fu%C3%9F_(foot)) there were dozens of different *standards* of length.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: The [ancient Greeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_units_of_measurement) and [Romans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_units_of_measurement) held to a 1:4 ratio of the palm to the foot. The medieval measures are based on the older ones.

Comment: The question seems unclear. Of course sometime in 10000-100000 years ago,  at least one human will have placed a human bone against something else as a gauge of measurement on at least one occasion in all that time. Is there evidence that human bones were *widely and systematically* used that way in prehistoric times? - I doubt it.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: No, it is not clear to me. There is the *homo mensura* exemplified in the "Vitruvian man" and then something weird again. Perhaps this will clarify: do you mean "a bone as the *basis* from which to derive a measurement" (then applied with sticks or rope as stand in of the same dimensions) or "an actual bone that is actually used as a measurement instrument, repeatedly" (like a relic, your "instrument" part)?

Comment: @LangLangC: I was wondering whether early humans, who are known to have employed animal bones in creating parts of various tools for millennia, might not have put actual human bones to such use.

Comment: It seems clear enough to me, but perhaps the answer is simply "no". At the least, noone seems able to bring an example to mind!

Comment: @AaronBrick: I am not a huge fan of uncertainties.

Comment: @Lucian It seems your last edit quite clarified the question, by taking out incomprehensible stuff. So I vote for reopening.

Comment: @Bregalad: Sometimes less is more. (Seems like my explanations confused rather than clarified).

Comment: @Lucian Exactly!

Comment: The foot was indeed standardised. In the ancient German city of Regensburg you can see the standard foot displayed on the town hall wall. Each city had its own foot, and if your town's foot was a bit bigger than average this was a sign of affluence; you were living "on the big foot".

Comment: The ell is also an ancient measure of length. This is the length of the forearm. In German one of the bones in the forearm is the Elle.

Comment: @RedSonja there is another question on here about ells that does not address any connection to bones. This could be an interesting answer.

Comment: @RedSonja The English words ell, ulna and elbow are all cognate as well https://www.etymonline.com/word/ell#etymonline_v_5744